# Why does Android application crash?

Tags: java, android

I have a very simple Android program and it's crashing all the time. The error message is:

```
2021-06-16 16:34:58.691 32268-32347/com.google.android.apps.maps E/emuglGLESv2_enc: a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0x82497e20
2021-06-16 16:34:58.691 32268-32347/com.google.android.apps.maps E/emuglGLESv2_enc: Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 0 attribute 5 vbo 44 allocedBufferSize 14832 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 19768
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    tools:context=".test1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Asia Gallery" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/japanImageButton"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/image" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

The Java code:

```
package co.il.myApp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialog;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class test1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageButton japan;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test1);

        japan = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.japanImageButton);
        japan.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if (japan == view)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Japan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In logcat look for `FATAL EXCEPTION` from your app, not just some random error logging from com.google.android.apps.maps

Comment: Just ound the error -the backgound image cause the problem